# Use a jira design system component in my hello world custom UI application when developping add-on for jira cloud

Tags: jira, add-on, forge, custom-ui, atlassian-forge

I generated a jira add-on app using Forge CLI.
i created the hello-world application using custom UI mode with jira-global tempalte.
i deployed and installed it and it worked like a charm. When i tried to get to the next step and use this component : https://atlassian.design/components/page-layout/examples   the (page-layout) , i choose to use the first component the basic one.
When i added the code used in my App.js i get an error at the level of this line of command :
`import { SlotLabel, SlotWrapper } from '../common';`.
i saw what they did in the CodeSandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/6lwfqv?module=/example.tsx&file=/example.tsx   , they created literraly all the tree to get the slotwraper and slotlabel component.

When i did the same thing, the ide return the error :
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './design-system/page-layout/examples/common' in 'C:\jira\pi_planner\static\hello-world\src'`

Here is a view of my project structure :

```
|-- src
|   `-- index.js
|-- static
|   `-- hello-world
|       `-- src
|           `-- design-system  
|               '-- page-layout
|                   '-- examples
|                       '-- common
|           `-- index.js
|           `-- App.js
|       `-- public
|           `-- index.html
|       `-- package.json
|       `-- package-lock.json
|-- manifest.yml
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
`-- README.md
```

Any one got a clue to help me fix the issue?
I'am still learning how to developp jira add-on with Atlassian forge CLI

- I tried copy past the component code but not working it doesn't find ../common in my project.
- I triend like in the codesandbox, creating the tree and putting the tsx files but i get the error that the module couldn't be found.

Comment: There is https://community.developer.atlassian.com/ community where developers using Forge are on daily basis, you can ask also there.